# Is uncut-gem actually uncut-gems?

Tags: discussion, tags

So while fixing up [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/107379/what-does-dusty-tinfoil-filled-bitch-refer-to) I was trying to fix the tags and found there was a tag for [uncut-gem](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncut-gem) with a question to it.

Now when I Google the titles I find [*Uncut Gems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncut_Gems) which is a 2019 film however I can't find *Uncut Gem* and google tries to correct me that it's *Uncut Gems*.

I am wondering about a few things if *Uncut Gem* and *Uncut Gems* are 2 different films:

- if so, how do we get around [uncut-gems](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncut-gems) is rejected because it's too similar to the existing [uncut-gem](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncut-gem)?
- if not, then should [uncut-gem](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncut-gem) be renamed to [uncut-gems](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncut-gems)?

Comment: Just to note that [tag:uncut-gems] can't be added until [tag:uncut-gem] has been roomba'd which will take a day or two.

Comment: As to the first point, you flag it for moderator attention, who can always rename tags and create new tags.

Answer (score 5):

The question that uses the [uncut-gem](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncut-gem) tag is [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/106549/46980). After a quick Google search, I've confirmed that it is in fact referring to *Uncut Gem**s***, and OP simply got the name wrong.

I can't find any evidence of a film called "Uncut Gem" without the plural, but I'd say that's irrelevant in this instance. The tag name is wrong, and should be corrected to [uncut-gems](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncut-gems). We don't need an [uncut-gem](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncut-gem) tag until and unless someone asks about a film that actually *is* called that.

---

The tag now has indeed been corrected, so I think we can consider this "case closed".